# Registered HTMLHelper class not working in specific area

Tags: htmlhelper

When trying to use a function from a custom service registered within my component, I have an issue.

So inside the backend boot function of my component I'm doing this:

```
public function boot(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    ...
    $this->getRegistry()->register('tools', new MyTools());
    ...
}
```

The tools are just a class containing different functions I need to use on different places.

I'm using it like this and I can use these functions everywhere. In backend, frontend, modules, plugins and also in my custom template.

Example:

```
echo HTMLHelper::_('tools.custom', $some, $args);
```

The only place I cannot use them is a layout override of the author layout, lying here:

```
mysite\templates\mytemplate\html\layouts\joomla\content\info_block\author.php
```

When trying to analyse and dig deeper i can see that the Joomla `HTMLHelper` always uses the registered service of my tools here:

```
// inside the _ HTMLHelper function
if (\array_key_exists($key, static::$registry)) {
    $function = static::$registry[$key];
    return static::call($function, $methodArgs);
}
```

Only when calling it from the layout override inside the template, it seems to not be registered and fails.

The message I get is

```
500 JHtmlMyTools not found.
```

That's strange because inside my template I also have custom layouts for `mod_menu` where I can successfully use my custom `HTMLHelper` functions.

Any idea what's happening here? Thanks.